# Identify device between installs iOS, like Whisper App

Tags: ios, objective-c, identifier

I am developing an app where I would like to be able to stop users from uninstalling the app and reinstalling to create a new user account. It's a fitness app and they get points/penalties depending on activity levels.

Now as far as I can tell I can only get two unique identifiers from the device, the Vendor ID which will be reset once the user uninstalls the app or the advertiser Id which the user can reset at will. So as far as I can see, no real way of doing it if the user is savvy enough.

So, how do whisper do it, I played with the app a while ago and upon reinstalling it it knew exactly who I was. As an experiment I uninstalled the app, reset my advertising if and restarted the phone. I then reinstalled the app and again it knew exactly who I was.

How is this possible? I thought the whole point of the user being able to reset these things is to allow for them to block tracking?

I would very much like to have this ability in my app, but cannot see any way with the current apple api's and guidelines to make it work?

Answer (score -1):

If you gat UDID of the device and save it to your database, you can always search from database  to check if this UDID already exists or not. You can get UDID by the code

```
NSString* uniqueIdentifier = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
```

Comment: That isn't the `UDID` that is the `UUID` or vendor identifier. The `UDID` isn't allowed to be used anymore for privacy reasons and Apple have removed all ways of being able to get it.

Comment: Yes my understanding of the above is that as long as an all using my cdn is installed then this ID will not change. But as soon as all apps by me are removed then this ID changes, so this doesn't help me.